# MySQL: SELECT only getting records based on "WHERE x LIKE '%?%'" in many-to-many relationship

Tags: mysql, sql, many-to-many, where-clause

Given these tables:

```
board_game
----------
id  name                       genre
1   The Game                   Strategy
2   The Game: Limited Edition  Strategy

board_game_piece_missing
------------------------
board_game_id  piece_id  missing_quantity
1              1         2
1              2         3
1              3         1
2              1         1

piece
-----
id  name           color
1   Soldier        Red
2   Ghost          Green
3   Ghost Soldier  Red/Green
```

Let's say I only want to find Strategy board games that have **Red-only** missing pieces (meaning the Red/Green Ghost Soldier piece does not count). In this case, I should only be finding game 2 (The Game: Limited Edition) because the only pieces missing are only red, like so:

```
 id  name                       genre
 2   The Game: Limited Edition  Strategy
```

How would I construct one query (preferably) or two queries maximum to do this?

This is the query I currently have so far, just in case I'm doing something wrong to begin with:

```
SELECT b.id, b.name, b.genre
FROM board_game b
LEFT JOIN board_game_piece_missing bp ON b.id = bp.board_game_id
LEFT JOIN piece p ON bp.piece_id = p.id
WHERE b.genre = 'Strategy'
-- Insert missing piece SQL here --
GROUP BY d.id
```

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can count the # of missing red and non-red colors in your having clause and only select games that have 0 non-red missing colors and 1 or more red missing colors

```
SELECT b.id, b.name, b.type
FROM board_game b
JOIN board_game_piece_missing bp ON b.id = bp.board_game_id
JOIN piece p ON bp.piece_id = p.id
WHERE b.genre = 'Strategy'
GROUP BY b.id
HAVING SUM(p.color <> 'Red') = 0
AND SUM(p.color = 'Red') > 0
```

Comment: +1 . . . Although I prefer:  `having sum(p.color <> 'Red') = 0 and sum(p.color = 'Red') > 0`.

Comment: Thank you, this works great for 1-2 colors. However, let's say there were 4 different possible colors (and double comibinations of these colors) in the `piece` table. How would I get all Red, Green and Blue missing pieces, including Red/Green, Red/Blue and Green/Blue combinations? I got this to work with two colors, but once I go to 3 or higher in my `HAVING SUM()` lines, it does not return anything.

Comment: @freddy_fit if you're trying to get games that have red blue and green missing pieces but no other missing pieces then you'd do `having sum(p.color not in ('red','blue','green')) = 0 and sum(p.color = 'red') > 0 and sum(p.color = 'blue') > 0 and sum(p.color = 'green') > 0` ... if this doesn't answer your question, please post a new question with more details and what you've tried